# Como cambiar texto con animacion CSS Fade in

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy tratando de cambiar los textos con una animación pero aun no logro como hacerlo tengo el siguiente código:

```css
.blink_me {
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
 <p>Here is a sentence <span class="blink_me" id="rotate">default</span> is what changes</p>

 <ul style="display:none">
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>bob</li>
  <li>next</li>
  <li>last</li>
  <li>PABLO</li>
  <li>ANDRES</li>
 </ul>
```

La idea es que se muestren los elementos de la etiqueta `li` y vallan cambiando algo como esto: [Animacion FadeIn](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZwXzdj) pero usando solo `CSS`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes tener dos animaciones:

- Una para que parpadee (que ya la tienes creada)
- Otra para que cambie el texto (por crear)

> Nota: originalmente había puesto una solución con `::before`/`::after`, pero no terminaba de animarse bien en algunos navegadores. Se puede revisar esa solución en el historial.

Puedes tener el texto en varios `span` dentro de y entonces mostrar/ocultar cambiando su ancho de 0 a auto (teniendo un `overflow: hidden`). Entonces lo que harías sería calcular los tiempos (tienes 6 palabras diferentes, si la animación dura 100% del tiempo, cada palabra deberá estar un 16.6%).

Entonces lo único que quedaría sería ajustar los tiempos de las animaciones para que el parpadeo coincida con el cambio de palabra.

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```css
.blink_me {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
}

.blink_me span {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: hideShow 6s linear infinite;
}

.blink_me span:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: -0s; }
.blink_me span:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: -1s; }
.blink_me span:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: -2s; }
.blink_me span:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: -3s; }
.blink_me span:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: -4s; }
.blink_me span:nth-child(6) { animation-delay: -5s; }

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes hideShow {
  0%, 16.6%, 33.33%, 100% { width: 0; }
  16.66%, 33.3% { width: auto; }
}
```

```html
<p>
  Here is a sentence 
  <span class="blink_me" id="rotate">
    <span>test1</span>
    <span>bob</span>
    <span>next</span>
    <span>last</span>
    <span>PABLO</span>
    <span>ANDRES</span>
  </span> 
  is what changes
</p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: como puedo hacer para que funcione en los diferentes navegadores? Ie, Mozila, Opera, Safari

Comment: al parecer va tocar hacerlo por Jquery por que IE no reconoce pseudo-elementos como ::before entonces no muestra la animacion

Comment: @zerokira añade los prefijos de navegador

Comment: Y en donde los agrego? puedes editar la respuesta, por favor :)

Comment: @zerokira ¿qué versión de IE no los reconoce? Puede que tengas que redefinirlos a `:before` en lugar de `::before` para IE8, pero desde IE9 `::before` y `::after` deberían funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: Estoy usando IE 11

Comment: aun colocando los prefix sigue sin funcionar, como te digo los :before como que los omite y no funciona correctamente en IE, Safari

Comment: He hecho pruebas. Parece que a los navegadores parece no gustarles del todo eso de animar pseudo elementos. Cuando llegue a un ordenador lo reviso y si no, someone se puede cambiar el html para animar elementos en lugar de pseudo elementos.

Comment: creo que lo mejor entonces seria hacerlo sin :pseudo-elementos, te agradezo mucho si me puedes ayudar :)

Comment: @zerokira lo he actualizado para que no utilice pseudo elementos. Requiere una solución un poco _hacky_ porque `display` no se anima como se debiera y hay que jugar con los valores del ancho/alto y el `overflow`. No es perfecto, pero también puedes optar por una solución con JavaScript (si no necesitas jQuery, podría hacerse de forma sencilla con JS puro).

Comment: eso de que jugar con el display no me gusta para nada jaja, lo mejor sera entonces usar jquery :(